# How can I solve this second order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So, I have to solve the following system
$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = x(t)y(t)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}y(t) = x(t)$$

I can just substitute $x(t)$ in the first equation and get
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t) = y(t)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$$
but I can't go further. I also tried to use python but gave me a weird function. How can I go on and solve this equation?

Edit: I tried integrating both sides and got
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y(t)^2}{2} + c_1$$
and then integrated again but got the wrong answer.

Comment: Note that the right-hand side is a derivative, so go ahead and integrate.

Comment: I integrated both sides and got the following (not sure though):

$$\frac{-1}{y(t)} = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{1}{y(0)}$$

where $y(0)$ is the value of $y(t = 0)$

Comment: This is not correct. Please edit the original post to include the details.

Comment: I edited my post. I'm still very new to solving differential equations, so any tips or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: OK, so don’t forget the constant of integration. Otherwise, you’re doing fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

From

$$
\cases{\dot x = x y\\
\dot y = x}
$$

after multiplying by $y$ the second ode and subtracting, we arrive at

$$
y\dot y -\dot x = 0\Rightarrow \frac 12y^2-x = C_1
$$

so we can proceed with

$$
\dot y = \frac 12y^2-C_1
$$

then

$$
y = -\sqrt{2C_1} \tanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{C_1} (t-2 C_2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$

etc.

Comment: I'm just struggling with finding the appropriate constants. For instance, if the initial value of $y(t)$ is $10^6$, the initial value of $x(t)$ is $1$, and the initial value of $\dot{y}$ is $-1$, how can I arrive to the same formula? I tried deriving it but $C_1 < 0$, resulting in some weird things.

Comment: If $C_1\lt 0$ we have $\sqrt{C_1}= i \sqrt{-C_1}$ and $\tanh(\sqrt{C_1}\mu) = i\tan(\sqrt{-C_1}\mu)$ so $i\cdot i = -1$

Answer (score 1):

Since after substitution you got a second-order ODE in $y$, solving it should give you an equation for $y(t)$ that has two integration constants: one when integrating from $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t)$ to $\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$, and one from $\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$ to $y(t)$. After the first integration, I recommend changing variable from $y$ to $\theta$ by substituting $y = \alpha \tan \theta$, where you should choose $\alpha$ so that the new ODE in $\theta$ and $t$ becomes straightforward to solve. Then after solving for $\theta(t)$, substitute back to get $y(t)$. Your final expression for $y(t)$ should look something like this

> $$y(t) = \sqrt{2c_1} \tan \left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{2}}(t - c_2)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Last steo of OP yields:
$$ \int\frac{dy}{y^2} dt=\int \frac{dt}{2} dt \implies -1/y=t/2+C \implies y(t)=\frac{-2}{t+2C}$$

Comment: Your integration is correct, but OP forgot the constant of integration, so that the integrand on the LHS should be $1/(y^2+C)$, which will result in an arctangent.